# How to speed up Select by location?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, performance, select

Has anyone had a similar "extreme slow" experience using "Select by location" (Toolbox) and "Spatial query" tool?

I've used both for selecting some points inside a polygon. The data was in SHPs and the point-dataset has 80.000 points (with a lot of attributes) - the poly-dataset is small.

The result was "within" ~14.000 points. QGIS 2.8 and 2.13 need around 10min for the task. I did the same now with ArcGIS 10.3 and it took 4-5 seconds.

Does someone know a better (faster) solution within QGIS ?

Comment: Not completely sure but what about creating a **spatial index** by either _Layer Properties > General > Create spatial index_ or _Vector > Data Management Tools > Create Spatial Index..._ and then running the tools?

Comment: Hi! Both datasets have already a spatial index... doing it natively SQL-based with Spatialite is also quite fast. The in QGIS used algorithm seems to be slow compared to ArcGIS or SQLite/Spatial.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems to this, and found that:
 - The slow issue only occurred on my computer, but was fine on other computers, therefore potentially a memory leakage issue on my computer
 - The issue fixed itself when I upgraded to QGIS 2.12.3

Comment: Did it on 3 different machines and OSes (QGIS 2.8 on Win, QGIS 2.13 on Win and QGIS 2.10 on Linux/Fedora) - always the same...